# Formula for calculating pitch rate

Tags: yeast, calculations, pitching-rate

I see a whole bunch of online pitch rate calculators such as [this one by Brewer's Friend](https://www.brewersfriend.com/yeast-pitch-rate-and-starter-calculator/), but I'm struggling to find the actual formula(e) used under the hood by them.

Does anybody know of any generally-accepted pitch rate formulas out there? Ideally I'd like to know what Brewer's Friend is using but I'll take anything thats in the ballpark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view the source of the BF website, there is some packed javascript in there that you can run through an online tool to pretty-print some mathematical calculations used on the site.

I've tried using those pitch rate calculators but so much of it is guesswork that it just seems pointless. I have no idea how many billion cells (slurry density) I have in my harvested yeast.

When I harvest my yeast, I pour it into three 16oz mason jars. I like to leave about an inch of beer at the top as a vapor barrier when storing in the fridge.

When I make beer, a few days prior I'll pull out a jar of slurry and give it a whiff. If it smells good, I'll make a starter and let it whirl on the stir plate a couple days. If the starter smells ok, I'll decant what I can and pitch the rest in my wort. I can usually see fermenter activity within a couple hours, depending on the temp.

Sometimes tools come along which add more drudgery and very little benefit. Whether the pitch tool is one of these, I don't know. For me though, I like to keep the rules simple and see what I can get away with. I want to have fun and make enjoyable beer.

Answer (score 2):

Common advice says 0.75 million cells/ml/°P for ales and 1.5 million cells/ml/°P for lagers. However more modern breweries are upping these numbers just a bit.

I can say that calculations really only work when you're using a hemacytometer to measure cell count. Any eyeballing or using cell counts on yeast packaging- the math is all out the window.

Comment: Always wondered hth anyone was measuring cell count 

Comment: @HomeBrew There's some dilution methods where you can get relatively close with naked-eye testing.

I do remember a reddit user (a sharp biologist who now runs The Yeast Bay yeast bank) spread around a naked-eye method that worked pretty good. [This is the link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Homebrewing/comments/1x9sx3/how_to_estimate_yeast_cell_count/), and scroll down for the comment from /u/biobrewer `YEAST COUNTING BY DILUTION` .

Comment: Cool info! There's a lot there to digest but the method of eyeballing turbidity to equite cell count seems practical enough.